# Why is shuffle False in the test imagedatagenerator?

Tags: classification, predict, imagedatagenerator

I am using a classification model that classifies normal and abnormal in binary through imagedatagenerator.
Training and validation generators have been performed and model training has performed well.
However, a question arose in the test generator.

The difference in classification performance indices between shuffle=True and False in the test generator is too large.

When shuffle=False, it results in a very good classification model.
shuffle=True gives 50% accuracy.

I've seen other users use the test generator, but I don't understand why shuffle is set to False. help?

I think the test accuracy is reliable because the data built in the test folder is also randomly shuffled when shuffling is performed.